# Inherited types in templates using CRTP

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, types, crtp

Here is a basic usage of CRTP to define a custom collection type:

```
template <class __B>
struct A
{
    typedef std::vector<__B> collection_type;
};
struct B: public A<B>
{
    collection_type X;
};
```

Used in a template

```
template <typename __T>
struct C: public A<C<__T>>
{
    // collection_type X; <--- this does not compile
    typename A<C<__T>>::collection_type X;
};
```

Why is the "typename ...::" part needed with C but not with B?

Comment: Unqualified lookup doesn't look into dependent base classes. And stop naming things `__T` and `__B`.

Comment: Stop naming thing `__T` and `__B`. See 17.6.4.3.2 Global names [global.names]
>Each name that contains a double underscore _ _ or begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase
letter (2.12) is reserved to the implementation for any use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`struct B` is a concrete class, not a template, and its definition does not depend on any parameters. So, when the compiler inherits it from `A<B>`, it instantiates the class `A<B>` from template `A`, sees the definition of `collection_type` in it and is happy.

`struct C` is a template, so `A<C<__T>>` depends on the parameter `__T`. `A` can be specialized, so the compiler has no idea of what `collection_type` will actually be, or even if it will exist or not. So, we have to tell the compiler where to look for `collection_type` (so, `A<C<__T>>::collection_type`), and that it is a type (so `typename A<C<__T>>::collection_type`).